# How to connect Beziersqlib to a remote server?

Tags: mysql, arduino, processing

I'm currently making my project using arduino and processing, but my beziersqlib doesn't seems to work on a remote server (Webhosting). Someone got an idea on how to make it work?
this is my processing code:

```
msql = new MySQL( this, "mysql17.000webhost.com", database, user, pass );

    if ( msql.connect() )
    {
        msql.query( "SELECT stat FROM tbl WHERE userid=8 AND lid=12346" );
        msql.next();
        println( "Status is: " + msql.getInt(1) );
     }
```